# Get the spectral decomposition from the singular value decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

I'm struggling with this task:

---

Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{3 \times 3}$ be a Hermitian matrix. Its singular value decomposition is given as follows:
$$
\mathbf{A}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} i & 0 & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} i \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
0 & -1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} i & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} i \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)^H
$$
Derive a spectral decomposition for $\mathbf{A}$ from the singular value decomposition and justify your answer.

---

What I saw:

- The SVD is given, we have $A = U\Sigma V^H$
- This is equiv. to $AV = U\Sigma$
- From there follows: $Av_1 = u_1\sigma_1$, $Av_2 = u_2\sigma_2$, $Av_3 = u_3\sigma_3$

How do i go from there?

Comment: Note that $V=UD$ where $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1,-1)$ and $\Sigma D$ is a diagonal matrix.